# TinyMCE display image with erong width and height after PHP rotation

Tags: tinymce, height, width, exif

This PHP script is handling upload and working with TinyMCE Editor. There is a problem though if an image has EXIF orientation meta data.The image rotated correctly but TinyMCE display the image with the wronf width and height. I need to pass the new width and height to TinyMCE but not sure how to do it?

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
//Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
    $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://127.0.0.1", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

    // Set the destination folder for image
    $month = strtolower(date('M'));
    $year = date('Y');
    $newspath = "img/news/";

    if (!is_dir("$newspath/$year/$month")) {
    mkdir("$newspath/$year/$month", 0777, true);
}
    $imageFolder = "$newspath/$year/$month/";

    reset ($_FILES);
    $temp = current($_FILES);
    if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
            if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
            } else {
                header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
                return;
            }
        }

        /*
            If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
            the configuration and enable the following two headers.
        */
        // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

        // Rewrite bad filenames
        $temp['name'] = preg_replace(array('/\s+/', '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\._]/', '/\.(?=.*\.)/', '/[\-]+/', '/[_]+/'), array('_', '', '_', '_', '_'), strtolower($temp['name']));

        // Verify extension
        if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"))) {

                header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
                return;
        }

        // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
        $tempname = $temp['name'];
        $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $tempname;
        $randompin = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
        // If file name already exists rename
        if (file_exists($filetowrite)) {
        $tempname =  $randompin . $tempname;
        $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $tempname;
        }

        // If EXIF Orientation data exists, rotate image as required
        $savetmpname = $temp['tmp_name'];
        function correctImageOrientation($savetmpname) {
            if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
                $exif = exif_read_data($savetmpname);
                if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
                    $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
                    if($orientation != 1){
                        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($savetmpname);
                        $deg = 0;
                        switch ($orientation) {
                            case 3:
                                $deg = 180;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                $deg = 270;
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                $deg = 90;
                                break;
                        }
                        if ($deg) {
                            $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);       
                        }
                        //Rewrite rotated image back to the disk
                        imagejpeg($img, $savetmpname, 75);
                    } // if there is some rotation necessary
                } // if have the exif orientation info
            } // if function exists     
        }
        // Move uploaded files and rotate if requireD
        move_uploaded_file($savetmpname, $filetowrite);
        correctImageOrientation($filetowrite);
        //}
        // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
        // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
        // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
        // echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));

        $passpath = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$tempname;

        echo json_encode(array('location' => $passpath));
    } else {
        // Notify editor that the upload failed
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, this works by swapping the width and height of the image if it is rotated 90 or 270 degrees, here is the exif function:

```
        // If EXIF Orientation data exists, rotate image as required
        $savetmpname = $temp['tmp_name'];
        function correctImageOrientation($savetmpname) {
            if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
                $exif = exif_read_data($savetmpname);
                if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
                    $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
                    if($orientation != 1){
                        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($savetmpname);
                        $imgwidth = imagesx($img);
                        $imgheight = imagesy($img);
                        //$imgwidth = ImagesX($img);
                        //$imgheight = ImagesY($img);
                        $deg = 0;
                        switch ($orientation) {
                            case 3:
                                $deg = 180;
                                $newimgwidth = $imgwidth;
                                $newimgheight = $imgheight;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                $deg = 270;
                                $newimgwidth = $imgheight;
                                $newimgheight = $imgwidth;
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                $deg = 90;
                                $newimgwidth = $imgheight;
                                $newimgheight = $imgwidth;
                                break;
                        }
                        if ($deg) {
                            $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);  
                            $img = imagecopyresized($img, $savetmpname, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newimgwidth, $newimgheight, $imgwidth, $imgheight); 
                        }
                        // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename
                        imagejpeg($img, $savetmpname, 75);
```